# Filter SQL Query contain Array

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query, to display Profile, one of the column contain Array of languages fluent in.

```
profile gender country               nationality fluent_in
    318 Male   United Arab Emirates  Lebanese    a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Arabic";i:1;s:7:"Bengali";}
    366 Female Lebanon               Lebanese    a:3:{i:0;s:6:"Arabic";i:1;s:7:"English";i:2;s:6:"French";}
    368 Male   Jordan                Australian  a:2:{i:0;s:7:"English";}
   2924 Male   United Arab Emirates  Lebanese    a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Arabic";i:1;s:7:"English";}
```

My question, **what i should add to the Query, to Filter query "English", AND "Arabic" ?**

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT p2p_to as profile, pm1.meta_value as gender, pm2.meta_value as country, pm3.meta_value as nationality , pm4.meta_value as fluent_in
FROM `wp_p2p`
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm1 ON (wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key='gender')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON (wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key='country')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm3 ON (wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm3.post_id AND pm3.meta_key='nationality')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm4 ON (wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm4.post_id AND pm4.meta_key='fluent_in')
WHERE `p2p_type` LIKE 'service_learn'
```

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays.  What is the data type of the final column?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`pm4.meta_value LIKE "%Arabic%" AND pm4.meta_value LIKE "%English%"`

You can put it in the WHERE clause or in the JOIN ON. It's better in the JOIN part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string comparisons:

```
SELECT p2p_to as profile, pm1.meta_value as gender, pm2.meta_value as country, pm3.meta_value as nationality , pm4.meta_value as fluent_in
FROM `wp_p2p` LEFT JOIN
     `wp_postmeta` pm1
     ON wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key = 'gender' LEFT JOIN
     wp_postmeta pm2
     ON wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'country' LEFT JOIN
     wp_postmeta pm3
     ON wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm3.post_id AND pm3.meta_key = 'nationality' JOIN
     wp_postmeta pm4
     ON wp_p2p.p2p_to = pm4.post_id AND pm4.meta_key = 'fluent_in'
WHERE `p2p_type` LIKE 'service_learn' AND
      pm4.meta_value like '%"English"%' AND
      pm4.meta_value like '%"Arabic"%' ;
```

Notice that I made the last `JOIN` an inner join because there needs to be a match.